# Pointer Understanding

Tags: pointers, go

I have struct type and referring address of the variable, but it does not reflect latest value of the variable in the `defer` function.

```golang
type XY struct {
    S string
}

func CloseP(x *XY) {
    if x != nil {
        fmt.Println("Pointer-Closing", x.S)
    }
}

func main() {

    xp2 := &XY{"Pointer-X2 First"}
    fmt.Println(xp2)
    defer CloseP( xp2  )
    xp2 = &XY{"Pointer-X2 Second"}
    fmt.Println(xp2)

}

Output

&{Pointer-X2 First}
&{Pointer-X2 Second}
Pointer-Closing Pointer-X2 First
```

Expected Output

```
0xc000086018
0xc000086018
Pointer-Closing Pointer-X2 Second
```

My questions are:

> 1. Why is it display with '&' in the actual output, where it suppose to print address of the variable.
> 2. Why defer function is not reflecting latest value of the 'xp2' variable ?

So for the **point 2**- I have implemented below function. Can someone tell me is this best way to resolve this problem.

```golang
func main() {
    xp2 := XY{"Pointer-X2 First"}
    defer CloseP( &xp2  )
    xp2 = XY{"Pointer-X2 Second"}
}
```

**Output is**

```
Pointer-Closing Pointer-X2 Second
```

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Why is it display with '&' in the actual output, where it suppose to print address of the variable

Take a look at the format options here:

https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/

`Println` is using the default `%v`, if you want to print the value of the pointer, you can use the `%p` format, like so:

```
fmt.Printf("Pointer-Closing %p\n", xp2)
```

> 2. Why defer function is not reflecting latest value of the 'xp2' variable ?

Take a look here:

https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover

```
A deferred function's arguments are evaluated when the defer statement is evaluated.
```

So at the time the `defer` is evaluated there, the pointer is referencing the first object, so that output is as expected.

Comment: Thanks for detail answer. Understood point#1 but is there any way to refer latest value whenever defer function executed? I have updated my question, I have used pointer to pass into defer function. @eugenioy is this right way?

Comment: @ShailendraSoni, "is there any way to refer latest value whenever defer function executed?" Yes, with a closure: https://play.golang.org/p/c39FKEePLa4